# October CMS: Blog Plugin - How to dynamically select category

Tags: php, laravel-5, octobercms

I'm using the blogPosts component from the Rainlab Blog plugin to provide a list of posts on the front page of a website.

We need to be able to switch category on the fly.

When the filter category is entered statically the filter works fine. The question is how to set this dynamically, ideally without a page refresh

Thanks for any tips

Comment: what you mean by page refresh ? you want to add category values in your dropdown dynamically ? If yes then check this out http://stackoverflow.com/questions/41392323/octobercms-call-another-plugins-data-in-current-plugins-dropdown

Comment: Thanks Mittul!
Here's what we want to happen.

* There a blog post list on the front page of the site 
* The blog post list component allows setting of a filter category
* We want to set the filter category of the **blogPosts** component by clicking on a button
* It would be best if that didn't involve a page refresh 

Any tips very welcome. Thanks for your comment

Comment: You can use javascript or jquery for that in plugin.

Comment: Cool thanks for the tip. Will try that