# OctoberCMS Builder Plugin backend dropdown

Tags: octobercms, octobercms-backend, octobercms-plugins

I would like to create a plugin where to create `Posts`, each post belong to 1 `Category`.

And there is a dropdown menu at the backend where you can choose which category the post belongs to when you are creating a post.

However, I want the the options in such dropdown depend on the model `Category` where the `Value` is `category.name` and `Key` is `category.id` instead of me typing the string into it.

Please help! Thanks

### Thanks to Dragontree's suggestions: here is my 1st EDIT:

I already have my relationship set as followings:

in `/models/Category.php`

```
public $hasMany = [
    'posts' => ['stephenli\plugin\Models\Posts']
];
```

in `/models/Post.php`

```
public $belongsTo = [
    'category' => ['stephenli\plugin\Models\Category', 'key' => 'category_id']
];       /* I tried with or without  'key' => 'category_id'*/
```

and used relation widget at the `Builder` Plugin,

in `/models/post/field.yaml`

```
category_id:
    label: 'stephenli.postgod::lang.plugin.categorypick_label'
    oc.commentPosition: ''
    nameFrom: name
    descriptionFrom: description
    emptyOption: 'No categories found'
    span: auto
    type: relation
```

where in `/models/post/columns.yaml`

```
category_id:
    label: 'stephenli.plugin::lang.plugin.categorypick_label'
    type: text
    searchable: true
    sortable: true
```

When I access to my `Post` Plugin and click the `Create` button or try to amend any existing record in `list`, the following error shows:

> Model 'plugin\Models\Post' does not contain a definition for 'category_id'.

### Final edit:

To sum up everything for any other people who encounter the same issue in the future, there are two methods to solve the problem

You can either

1. Use `Dropdown` widget and change the options with [detailed solution here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/41392323/octobercms-call-another-plugins-data-in-current-plugins-dropdown) provided by @Mittul At TechnoBrave
2. Or directly use `Relation` widget as provided in the suggested solution by @dragontree

Comment: You have your answer here - https://stackoverflow.com/questions/41392323/octobercms-call-another-plugins-data-in-current-plugins-dropdown

Comment: Hi Mittul, thanks for your suggestion. I looked through a bit of your answer but I think what dragontree suggested seems to be a more suitable one using the relation widget. Let's dig into it a bit more. Thanks again

Comment: Yes that is also worth to use. You can make it work which suits the best to you. Hope this link helped you.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There are several ways to [define the dropdown options](https://octobercms.com/docs/backend/forms#field-dropdown).

But in this case its sounds like you should be using the `relation` [widget](https://octobercms.com/docs/backend/forms#widget-relation) instead on a normal dropdown:

```
category:
    label: Category
    type: relation
    nameFrom: name
```

PS. This also requires you to define the relations in the `Post` and `Category` models. But you should do that anyway.

It is also worth noting that the field name (in fields.yaml) should match the name of the relation.

Comment: Hi dragontree, thanks for your response again. However please look up at my edit to see what is wrong after my edit. Thanks!

Comment: The field name (in fields.yaml) should match the name of the relation. So instead of `category_id`, you should be using just `category`

Comment: For anyone following, it's worth nothing that when dragontree says "It is also worth noting that the field name (in fields.yaml) should match the name of the relation." this is literally correct.  In my case public $belongsTo = [
        'course_level_id' => ['Geomantics\Coursetech\Models\CourseLevel'],
    ]; and         course_level_id:
            nameFrom: name